# Angular Input vs RxJS for 30+ components

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-components

My app's performance is drastically deteriorating as soon as there is some data to handle (a set of 60+ objects). Which is insane, because there is really not much going on.

I have an array of objects, which then needs to get filtered through and displayed in a calendar-like layout. For now every "day" of that calendar is a component, which extends a base "day" component which in turn subscribes to a globally held subject holding the aforementioned array of objects. Which means for 5 weeks in a month view I have 35 subscriptions on one page (that's not counting subscriptions for other parts of UI). I suspect the number of subscriptions makes it so less responsive to user actions.

Which alternative approach could boost performance if I have one "source of truth" which needs to be filtered 35 times on one page depending on several filters (like, mode, layout, date)?

I know `@Input` could theoretically do the trick, but when I tried it, it seemed like even worse of an option. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the `Change Detection Strategy` to `OnPush`, with that, angular will check for changes only when the values of the `@Input` variables changes, reducing processing.

```js
@Component({
  template: `...`,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

You can get more info about that config [here](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4).

Comment: Thanks! I've never considered this way – and it did make a difference. Now the performance is as good as expected. However as I have multiple parent-child trees I need to see why some of them behave like nothing happens first and only after moving a mouse around trigger the expected change loop. I have surely provided ChangeDetectorRef and trigger it, too. :/

Comment: nice, maybe you need to refactor these child components to be `pure` (without mutating the @Input variables).